# To write a trigger for INSERT as well as UPDATE in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2017

I have written a trigger which should fire when an INSERT or UPDATE happens to a table "COST_HDR" and the DML should update one of the columns of this table i.e. "CMPL_STS" to 'C'.
My trigger is not working as expected. If the CMPL_STS is directly updated to 'C' as a new record, trigger works as expected. But if it is updated to 'D' as a new record and then to 'C' as an update, trigger fails to insert any record in TMP_XNS table.

Can anyone check what is wrong:

```
CREATE TRIGGER MyTrigger
ON [COST_HDR]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @UpdtStamp    DATETIME    =  GETUTCDATE()
  --
  IF UPDATE (CMPL_STS)
  BEGIN
  INSERT INTO [TMP_XNS]
  (
    HDR_UID,
    UPDT_STAMP
  )
         SELECT I.HDR_UID,
                @updtStamp
           FROM INSERTED I
LEFT OUTER JOIN DELETED D
             ON D.HDR_UID = I.HDR_UID
            AND ISNULL(I.CMPL_STS,'N') <> ISNULL(D.CMPL_STS,'N')  
          WHERE I.CMPL_STS = 'C'
                
  END
  --    
END
GO
```

Comment: MySQL and SQL Server? That code will not run on both - which one are you using?

Comment: sql server @jarlh

Comment: IF UPDATE() does not do what you might think - search the internet for discussions. But more importantly, what does "trigger fails" mean exactly? And there is NEVER a good reason to declare a flag variable as `VARCHAR(1)`. There is nothing variable here - but it is not used either. And I suggest you write 2 separate triggers for now and get them both working correctly. Then combine them if you REALLY have a good reason to do so.

Comment: @SMor - Updated my question.. Missed to remove the unused variable. And please check the issue description once again. I have updated it now.. "Trigger Fails" means trigger is not able to insert data in TMP_XNS table

Comment: And again - break your trigger up into separate insert / update versions. Let's address insert first. For an insert, what happens? Does the "action" depend on the value of CMPL_STS in the inserted rows? Note that IF UPDATE returns TRUE for an insert ALWAYS. And FWIW - why the cryptic table and column names?

Comment: Best way to compare `inserted` and `deleted` is `SELECT primary_key, col2 FROM inserted EXCEPT SELECT primary_key, col2 FROM deleted` this deals with nulls nicely. You should also have `SET NOCOUNT ON;` at the top

Comment: @SMor yes you are right.the action depends on the value of CMPL_STS in the inserted rows.

Comment: You should get a record added in `TMP_XNS` when updating `CMPL_STS` from "D" to "C". If it does not add a record the issue is somewhere else. Show us your update statement.